# How to filter the select-options field

Tags: javascript

I need little help with the JS code. When I choose a 'City' field value, the next select field should be 'Route'. When I select 'Route' value, the 'Position' field should filter only the positions(values) that are included in the 'Route' value.
Example:
I have route: Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3
In position field only Pos1, Pos2, and Pos3 options should be displayed

My attempt is below, but it doesn't work :(
How can I solved this issue? Thank you in advance!

```js
    document.getElementById("city").addEventListener("change", function(){

        var routeValues = Array.from(document.getElementById("route").options).map(e => e.value);

        var posValues = Array.from(document.getElementById("position").options).map(e => e.value);


        for (var i = 0; i < routeValues.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < posValues.length; j++) {
                if (routeValues[i].toLowerCase().includes(posValues[j].toLowerCase())) {
                    // show option
                }else{
                   //hide option
                }
            }
          }
        })
```

```html
<select id="city">
  <option value="city1">City1</option>
  <option value="city2">City2</option>
</select>

<select id="route">
  <option value="Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3">Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3</option>
  <option value="Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6">Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6</option>
</select>

<select id="position">
  <option value="Pos1">Pos1</option>
  <option value="Pos2">Pos2</option>
  <option value="Pos3">Pos3</option>
  <option value="Pos4">Pos4</option>
  <option value="Pos5">Pos5</option>
  <option value="Pos6">Pos6</option>
  <option value="Pos7">Pos7</option>
  <option value="Pos8">Pos8</option>
  <option value="Pos9">Pos9</option>
  <option value="Pos10">Pos10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try setting display: none style attribute to the option to hide and display: block to the one that you should see. Eventually you could use disabled attrbiute too...

Comment: Do you also want to filter routes according to the selected city? or just the positions according to the route?

Comment: Just the positions are enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code snippets. You can try two options for this.

### 1. Hide unwanted Tags

You can take the selected route value and hide irrelevant fields using `display: none` style rule.

```js
function setPositions(value) {
    const routeValues = value.split('-').map(val => val.trim());
    const posOptions = document.getElementById("position").options;

    for (var i = 0; i < posOptions.length; i++) {
        if (routeValues.includes(posOptions[i].value)) {
            posOptions[i].style.display = 'block'
        } else {
            posOptions[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("route").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    setPositions(e.target.value)
})

window.onload = () => {
   setPositions(document.getElementById("route").value);
}
```

```html
<select id="city">
  <option value="city1">City1</option>
  <option value="city2">City2</option>
</select>

<select id="route">
  <option value="Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3">Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3</option>
  <option value="Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6">Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6</option>
</select>

<select id="position">
  <option value="Pos1">Pos1</option>
  <option value="Pos2">Pos2</option>
  <option value="Pos3">Pos3</option>
  <option value="Pos4">Pos4</option>
  <option value="Pos5">Pos5</option>
  <option value="Pos6">Pos6</option>
  <option value="Pos7">Pos7</option>
  <option value="Pos8">Pos8</option>
  <option value="Pos9">Pos9</option>
  <option value="Pos10">Pos10</option>
</select>
```

### 2. Render only selected tags

Or you can render the only the relevant tags in the position field.

```js
function setPositions(value) {
    output = '';
    const routeValues = value.split('-').map(val => val.trim());

    routeValues.forEach(e => {
        output += '<option value="' + e + '">' + e + '</option>';
    });

    document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = output;
}

document.getElementById("route").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    setPositions(e.target.value)
})

window.onload = () => {
   setPositions(document.getElementById("route").value);
}
```

```html
<select id="city">
  <option value="city1">City1</option>
  <option value="city2">City2</option>
</select>

<select id="route">
  <option value="Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3">Pos1 - Pos2 - Pos3</option>
  <option value="Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6">Pos4 - Pos5 - Pos6</option>
</select>

<select id="position"></select>
```

In both examples, `window.onload` event listener is used to change the positions field on initial load of the webpage.